# How to properly use AdaptiveAvgPool for global pooling?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to convert a model which uses `Flatten`/`Linear` as the final layer to use global pooling with `AdapativeAvgPool1d`/`Linear`. The output dimensions of the Linear layer after the global pooling are messing up the training epochs. I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (64,4) (64,)
```

### Model with Flatten-->Linear (works)

`conv1d --> relu --> maxpool1d --> Flatten --> Linear`:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=128, stride=16, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.LazyLinear(n_classes)
    )
==========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
==========================================================================================
Sequential                               --                        --
├─Conv1d: 1-1                            [64, 32, 505]             4,128
├─ReLU: 1-2                              [64, 32, 505]             --
├─MaxPool1d: 1-3                         [64, 32, 252]             --
├─Flatten: 1-4                           [64, 8064]                --
├─Linear: 1-5                            [64, 4]                   32,260
==========================================================================================
```

### Model with AdaptiveAvgPool1d-->Linear (output dimension wrong)

I want the output of this implementation to match that of the previous one, where the output shape coming out of the `Linear` layer is `[64,4]`

```
    model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=128, stride=16, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(1),
            nn.LazyLinear(n_classes)
    )    
==========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
==========================================================================================
Sequential                               --                        --
├─Conv1d: 1-1                            [64, 32, 505]             4,128
├─ReLU: 1-2                              [64, 32, 505]             --
├─MaxPool1d: 1-3                         [64, 32, 252]             --
├─AdaptiveAvgPool1d: 1-4                 [64, 32, 1]               --
├─Linear: 1-5                            [64, 32, 4]               8
==========================================================================================
```

Comment: You can't  replace nn.Flatten with nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d because they don't do the same thing. You still need to add nn.Flatten() after nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d to have the same output shape.

Comment: Does that prevent the model from being translation invariant? That is, if it's trying to find an object in the data, can it still find the object at various offsets even if all offsets are not in the training data?

Comment: @A.Mounir - You are correct. Do you want to make your comment an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: okay, I added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace nn.Flatten with nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d because they don't do the same thing. You still need to add nn.Flatten() after nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d to have the same output shape.